# SQL get duplicates created within n seconds, update f key row in other table, delete dups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table InspectionNotes - I am able to get duplicate notes that are created within n seconds - this works well.

Problem is when I try to delete where rn > 1 I hit a foreign key constraint - in 
InspectionHoldDurations column PutOnHoldNoteID.

table Inspection Notes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InspectionNotes](
[InspectionNoteID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[InspectionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[UserRoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Notes] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[CurrentInspectionStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[InspectionNoteTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[QuickAnswerID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[Reviewed] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_InspectionNotes_Reviewed]  DEFAULT ((0)),
[DateReviewed] [datetime] NULL,
[ReviewedByUserRoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InspectionNotes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Table InspectionHoldDurations

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InspectionHoldDurations](
[InspectionHoldDurationID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[InspectionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[PutOnHoldByRoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[TookOffHoldByRoleID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
[TotalHoldDurationMinutes] [int] NULL,
[ExpirationDate] [datetime] NULL,
[PutOnHoldNoteID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[TakeOffHoldNoteID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[InspectionHoldDurationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My current query to delete duplicates:

```
;WITH CTE1
AS (
SELECT  
[InspectionNoteID],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by InspectionID, Notes,UserRoleID,CurrentInspectionStatusId,InspectionNoteTypeID,QuickAnswerID,Reviewed,DateReviewed,ReviewedByUserRoleID,DATEDIFF(ss,'1/1/1970',CreatedOn) / 10000 ORDER BY createdon ASC) AS rn
FROM [DBO].[InspectionNotes] 
)
DELETE inote
FROM
[DBO].[InspectionNotes] inote
INNER JOIN 
CTE1
ON inote.InspectionNoteID = CTE1.[InspectionNoteID]
where CTE1.rn > 1
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DBO].[InspectionHoldDurations] WHERE PutOnHoldNoteID = CTE1.InspectionNoteID or TakeOffHoldNoteID = CTE1.InspectionNoteID)
```

I want to get rid of the  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DBO].[InspectionHoldDurations] and instead update this table with corresponding row from CTE1 where rn = 1 - then delete from InspectionNotes where rn > 1.  I have tried this and keep getting fkey error.

Comment: You could use a merge statement. That lets you set those two conditions in two separate clauses. Alternatively, assuming you want them to be one atomic transaction, just do your delete and updates separately and  wrapped in an explicit transaction